# Prolong bounty period

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have a question that has not received enough attention and therefor I created a bounty for it. Now I have got a couple of answer which seems very promising, but I am still trying things out and also have a dialog regarding the current answers. At this time the bounty is ending and I would really like to be able to prolong the time here so I can award the correct answer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not, bounties only last for 7 days and there’s no way to extend the period. There’s a one day grace period once it ends though, giving you another 24 hours to award the bounty.

You can also start a new bounty when the current one finishes, either to encourage more answers, or simply to reward an existing answer. But the nature of the system will require you to set a higher bounty than you originally did, and the original bounty won’t be refunded.

Comment: That's pretty sad since I many times have not had enough time to really go through each answer before the bounty period ends.

Comment: The purpose of a bounty is to get extra attention on the question, it's a form of advertising if you will. Just like in other walks of life, you can't continue to advertise things past the date which you've paid for them to be advertised until. It's made pretty clear up-front what the length/nature of the bounty will be, and personally I think 6/7 days (which is how long ago you got the 3 answers on it) is a more than generous amount of time to review them. Unfortunately that wont be what everyone is hoping for, but it's a good system and I think it's fair to say it works as designed